# что это за адрес в gdb asm?

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, gdb

```
(gdb) print $ebp+4
$3 = (void *) 0xbffff74c
(gdb) x/x 0xbffff74c
0xbffff74c: 0x08049116
(gdb) x/x 0x08049116
0x8049116 <__libc_start_main+390>:  0xe8240489
```

тут пролог функции.
что такое 0xbffff74c?
я думал стек начинается с адреса  вида 0x080448000 и по нему бегает регистр ESP, а тут смущает 0xbffff74c.

Comment: 0x08049116 это адреса программы(секторов), а это адрес стека 0xbffff74c, тогда наверно откуда начинает расти стек, с какого адреса и кто определяет, компилятор или ОС?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Определяет libc, я думаю (точнее ELF loader, _ld.so_ который). Стек у вас изначально на `0xc0000000`.

Answer (score 0):

Данный ответ для 32 разрядного приложения.

`0xbffff74c` - это адрес значения адреса возврата в стеке.
Адрес, по которому будет взято значение адреса возврата и присвоено регистру `EIP` в конце функции командой `RET`.

Для лучшего понимания - в момент вызова функции, адрес следующей инструкции кладётся в стек, затем происходит переход к вызываемой функции. Начало функции стандартно именуют прологом, в котором сохраняют значение регистра `EBP` (кладут на стек), после регистру `EBP` присваивается значение верха стека из регистра `ESP`, таким образом `EBP` указывает на своё прошлое значение (адрес в стеке), которое хранится в стеке. И так как стек растёт вниз, то есть адреса растут вниз (от большего к меньшему), мы можем обратится к элементам лежащим за регистром `EBP` прибавляя к нему число кратное 4 (кратное 4, т.к. речь идёт о 32-разрядном процессе). Но мы также помним, что за прошлым значением регистра `EBP` на стеке лежал адрес возврата (адрес следующей инструкции, после вызова функции/процедуры). Следовательно, чтобы обратиться к адресу возврата, нужно прибавить к значению регистра `EBP` 4. Но делать этого не приходится, редко функции потребуется обращаться к адресу возврата таким образом, он нужен лишь для инструкции `RET`. Инструкция `RET` берёт последнее значение лежащее на стеке и присваивает его регистру `EIP`, однако перед её использованием необходимо подготовить стек (удалить выделенные на стеке локальные переменные функции, восстановить использованные регистры в функции, в том числе регистр `EBP`).

На самом деле, инструкцию `RET` можно заменить парой других инструкций:

```
pop eax
jmp eax
```

Однако это неэффективно и теряется значение регистра, в данном случае регистра `EAX`.